# How to pass an object to query string in javascript using getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have the below file that passes variables in query string.

**What I am able to do**

1. Get `document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML` and save it in
   `var getthis`.
2. Get value selected `$('#first').val();` and save it in `var from`

**What I am not able to do**

1. Get this values `document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML`, `document.getElementById("list2").innerHTML`, `document.getElementById("list3").innerHTML` and save the it in `var data` in this format `var data = { seats_booked: [ 'B2', 'B5', 'A20' ] };`.

I would like to know how to do this, since in query string I can then be able to get the variables using PHP.

I hope my question is clear and help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```html
<?php 
$str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
parse_str($str);
echo  $seats_booked[0];
?>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li id="getthis">list</li>
    </ul>
    <select id="first" name="first">
      <option value="10">First</option>
      <option value="11">Second</option>
      <option value="12">Third</option>
      <option value="13">Forth></option>
    </select>
    <ul>
      <li id="list1">B2</li>
      <li id="list2">B5</li>
      <li id="list3">A20</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="next" name="next">Next Step</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#next").click(function() {
          var data = { seats_booked: [ 'B2', 'B5', 'A20' ] };
          var result = $.param(data);
          var first = $('#first').val();                            
          var getthis = document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML;
          window.location = '?first='+first+'&getthis='+getthis+'&result='+result;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're sending the values to php, any specific reason why you are not wrapping them in `<form>` tag?

Comment: You can pass  multiple value as comma separated value e.g. ?seats_booked=B2, B5, A20 . and parse this result with split

Comment: @anomepani — You can, but why would you when PHP has a built in way (`[]`) of expressing multiple values as an array and jQuery has a function to generate data in that format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
<ul class="seats_booked">
<li id="list1">B2</li>
<li id="list2">B5</li>
<li id="list3">A20</li>
</ul>
var seats_booked = [];
$("ul.seats_booked li").each(function() { seats_booked.push($(this).text()) });
var data = {};
data["seats_booked"]=seats_booked;
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply When using your method I am getting `&results=B2,B5,A20` is there a way to get this `&result=seats_booked[]=B2&seats_booked[]=B5&seats_booked[]=A20`

Comment: the code work that way here the link to an example https://jsfiddle.net/pyz19zjc/1/

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.param` converts a data structure to the format used for query strings. Whole query strings. Not bits of query string<sup>*</sup>.

Put all your data in a query string, then use `param` on it.

```
var result = { seats_booked: [ 'B2', 'B5', 'A20' ] };
var first = $('#first').val();                          
var getthis = document.getElementById("getthis").innerHTML;

var data = {
    result: result,
    first: first,
    getthis: getthis
};

var query = jQuery.param(data);

window.location = "?" + query;
```

---

<sup>*</sup> more precisely, it converts to a set of key=value pairs suitable for a query string, so you can join them up yourself. Your problem is that you are taking the key=value pairs and then trying to use them as a single query string value. But you're also failing to encode the rest of the data properly, and using `param` for the whole thing is much cleaner and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/5p6k11ny/
I have only changed window.location to console.log

```
var data = { seats_booked: [] };
data.seats_booked.push(document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML);
data.seats_booked.push(document.getElementById("list2").innerHTML);
data.seats_booked.push(document.getElementById("list3").innerHTML);
```

Ofc, you could do it in some loop like

```
"list" + i
```